# How can I use columns value from nested select in main select?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, ora-00904

I'm trying to execute this SQL in Oracle:

```
select z.*
  from (select (CASE
                 WHEN trunc(to_date('01.02.2015', 'DD.MM.YY'), 'MM') =
                      to_date('01.02.2015', 'DD.MM.YY') THEN
                  trunc(ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -1), 'MM')
                 ELSE
                  trunc(sysdate - 1)
               END) as sd,
               trunc(sysdate) ed
          from dual) t,
       (SELECT *
          FROM table(SOMEOWNERUSER.SOMEPACKAGE.getPipelinedTable(to_char(t.sd,
                                                                       'dd.mm.yyyy'),
                                                               to_char(t.ed,
                                                                       'dd.mm.yyyy')))) z
```

But I get error `ORA-00904: "T"."SD": invalid identifier`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try getting rid of the whole query `from dual`. Just use the case expression inside the `getPipelinedTable` call. You can't reference columns across the queries that way. SQL Server has `cross apply` for that but I don't know if Oracle has an equivalent. I don't think you need it though. If that doesn't work, you'll probably just need to initialize some variables with the arguments you want to pass.

Comment: Your reference to columns t.sd and t.ed in the second subquery is causing the error. You need to correlate your second sub-querry with the result of t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to directly reference the table() in the same level join as the t subquery:

```
create type dt_type as object (dt date);
/

create type dt_tab as table of dt_type;
/

create or replace function getpipelinedtable (p_sd date, p_ed date)
return dt_tab
as
  l_tab dt_tab := dt_tab();
begin
  for i in 1 .. (p_ed - p_sd) + 1
  loop
    l_tab.extend;
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := dt_type(p_sd -1 + i);
  end loop;

  return l_tab;
end getpipelinedtable;
/

SELECT z.*
FROM   (SELECT (CASE WHEN TRUNC (TO_DATE ('01.02.2015', 'DD.MM.YY'), 'MM') = TO_DATE ('01.02.2015', 'DD.MM.YY') 
                          THEN TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -1), 'MM') 
                     ELSE TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) 
                END) AS sd,
                TRUNC (SYSDATE) ed
        FROM   DUAL) t,
        TABLE (  getpipelinedtable (t.sd, t.ed) ) z;

DT        
----------
01/01/2015
02/01/2015
03/01/2015
04/01/2015
05/01/2015
<snip>
06/02/2015
07/02/2015
08/02/2015
09/02/2015

drop function getpipelinedtable;
drop type dt_tab;
drop type dt_type;
```

Comment: Boneist, thank you very mutch! This is it. Next my question was be "how do same thing if instead of TABLE(someFunc()) was select * from some_table?". But, I understand that need to use INNER JOIN: `... t, inner join some_join_table jt on jt.created >= t.sd and jt.created < t.ed`

Comment: Yes, you could do an inner join (although you'd remove the comma just after the `t` and before the `inner join`). It entirely depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to remove comma after `t`. Thanks.